# How to find a specific word in a string and add a character before the string in php?

Tags: php, string

I have a string `This is a string` and i want to add a character `#` before a word but i don't know how to do that in php.

I have tried this code:

```
$string = 'This is a string';

substr_replace($string, '#', stripos($string, 'a'), 0);
```

It is working fine but the problem is that if i want to add '#' before 'is' then it will give the following output.

`Th#is is a string a string`

I am looking for a function which can find a particular word and add a character before that word.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = preg_replace('/\bis\b/i', '#$0', $string);
```

`\b` signifies a *word boundary*, the `/i` makes the whole thing case insensitive (optional, but probably a good idea). Learn more about regular expressions [here](http://regular-expressions.info) so you can alter this as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your help but i want # only before one word in a string if i provide the string 'This is a string and it is working fine' then it is producing 'This #is a string and it #is working fine'. But what i want is it should produce like this 'This #is a string and it is working fine'

Comment: `preg_replace` has a `$limit` parameter. Set it to `1`. http://php.net/preg_replace

Comment: @RohitKhatri Use `preg_replace` with a limit like e.g. `preg_replace('/\bis\b/i', '#$0', $string, 1)`. Details here: http://es1.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: @RohitKhatri Added an answer containing the working information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you tried right just use strrpos() in place of stripos().

```
$newstr=substr_replace($temp, '#', strrpos($temp, 'is'),0);
```

refer http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strpos.asp for difference and to learn other strpos() function.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/function.preg-replace) for this task. Also specify `1` for the *limit param* of this PHP function to limit the maximum possible replacements to 1.

Here is an example of how you might implement this function:

```
$string = 'This is a string and it is working fine';

$result = preg_replace('/\bis\b/i', '#$0', $string, 1);
```

In this case $result would contain the following:

`This #is a string and it is working fine`

The regex used (`'/\bis\b/i'`) is made up of the following syntax:

`//` => The enclosing [delimiters](http://php.net/regexp.reference.delimiters) (before and after the pattern)

`\b` => Specifies a [word boundary condition](http://php.net/regexp.reference.escape)

`/i` => (optional) This is a [pattern modifier](http://php.net/regexp.reference.internal-options) that sets the pattern to case-insensitive (caseless)

`/u` => (optional - not included in example pattern) This is another [pattern modifier](http://php.net/regexp.reference.internal-options) that makes the string being treated as UTF-8. Use in case you have strings containing UTF-8 encoded characters.

**A little side note about regex delimiters:** *Instead of slashes (/) you may also use other characters as delimiter like e.g. hash signs (#) and tildes (~). If the delimiter needs to be matched inside the pattern it must be escaped using a backslash. If it appears often inside the pattern, it's a good idea to choose another delimiter in order to increase readability. (Source: http://php.net/regexp.reference.delimiters)*